# Av foundation capturing image location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

my partial code to store location with image.

```
CLLocation *location = self.filteredLocation ;
                NSNumber *latitude  = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.filteredLocation.coordinate.latitude];
                NSNumber *longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.filteredLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Now since i live in india..i always get the latitude and longitude in positive values.

The current situation is that `latitude` and `longitude` comes as `28` and `72` respectively ...so  no + sign before them...however if i log **location** ..it shows the values with **+**.
i want to know if **-** will come if app is somewhere in that region..i can't test it in simulator ..since this code comes after code of `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` photo capture..which isn't available in simulator.

**My other doubts :**

- Any way to get location with avfoundation itself.
- i take the image at around 2-3 seconds after the app starts..right
  now i get the location in this much time..can anyone confirm if
  location manager is usually fast..or if i can make something to catch
  location fastest way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose you can use predefined coordinate of location.

***Example*** `self.filteredLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.3,-2.371).`
(set it initially as well as in location delegate, because if it gets called then we will still have this location as current one).

so when you will log self.filteredLocation it will show `< +53.3,-2.371 >` in its description.

`AVFoundation` framework does not have any way to do this. As apple has provide CoreLocation framework for this purpose.

Even `CoreLocationManager` will be unable to tell you about its fastness. It depends on the device's previous location history. If you are accessing your current location for the very first time then it will take time, but if you have accessed it just in previous run then it will be quicker.

****Correction:****

It's my mistake that I have assigned CLLocationCoordinate2D to a CLLocation object.
it should be :

CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:+53.3 longitude:-2.371];
or you can use other method for initialization.

Now when you will convert any of this double(latitude/longitude) in NSNumber it will have its property(signed/unsigned) with it. So it it is negative then NSNumber will be negative.

Comment: what about the - values in the location?

Comment: other values are acuracy, speed, course, date and time. So we can consider acuracy, speed, and course will be similar but date time will be as per device's date settings, so change it via date settings.

Comment: you didn't understand my question...lets say i have a location < -24,-34> will  ` NSNumber *latitude  = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.filteredLocation.coordinate.latitude];` give me a positive value or negative?

Comment: As both the values are negative then NSNumber *latitude(and longitude) will return you negative value.